# sending enter signal automatically?

Tags: java, terminate, enter

I'm using a code to recover passwords. when a user requested to reset password, it send a SMS to user's phone. my problem is that it gives me this output in the middle of the runtime.

===============================================================================

Now Sleeping - Hit enter to terminate.

but I want to send the enter signal automatically so the job will be terminated automatically.how can I do this?

My code is below:

```
                if (rs3.next()) {
                    String port = "COM3"; //Modem Port.
                    int bitRate = 460800; //this is also optional. leave as it is.
                    String modemName = "Huawei E165G"; //this is optional.
                    String modemPin = ""; //Pin code if any have assigned to the modem.
                    String SMSC = "+947100003"; //Message Center Number ex. Mobitel

                    GsmModem gsmModem = new GsmModem();
                    GsmModem.configModem(port, bitRate, modemName, modemPin, SMSC);
                    gsmModem.Sender(mobileno, "Your new password is "+rs3.getString("password")+"  Please change your password in your next login. >>Fast Inventory<<"); // (tp, msg) 
                    System.out.println("Code came here");

                    Statement s2=Db.connectDb().createStatement();
                    s2.executeUpdate("UPDATE user SET lockstatus='0' WHERE uid='"+username.getText()+"'");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm using SMSlib.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You have a thread or something? What is the program that is hold with "Now Sleeping - Hit enter"? Can you show some code?

Comment: you want to send Enter from your java app. to terminal

Comment: take a look at the robot class. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: Where's the "Hit enter" in the code?

Comment: Christian Vielma :I have added my code . please revised and give me a solution.

Arpit : Nope. I want my program to send the enter command automatically so the job will be terminated.

Comment: Christian Vielma : I didn't code anything to display Hit enter. It's comming from the SMSLib jar file.

Comment: I've never used that library, where can I see a javadoc of the classes? Which class do you guess is printing the text "hit enter"? It seems like a thread, if you know the class maybe you'll be able to signal the thread to end that part. How do you run this program? from console? can you execute it unattended?

Comment: well. I also don't know much about this.This is my first time using SMSLib.    http://smslib.org

I'm running this from NetBeans.